# Parsing JSON with Logstash to insert it into Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to achieve, that a logstash instance reads a JSON file, and sends it to an elasticsearch cluster. I am using the following pipeline configuration file:

```
input
{
    file
    {
            path => ["/path/to/proba.json"]
            type => "json"
            start_position => "beginning"
            ignore_older => 0

    }
}

output
{
    elasticsearch
    {
            hosts => "http://172.19.238.10:9200"
            index => "proba"
    }
}
```

I would expect, that a new index with the name 'proba' appears in elasticsearch containing the JSON indexed, but nothing is really happening. The logstash logs:

```
[2017-11-01T10:12:46,540][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:46,542][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:46,553][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"arcsight", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/x-pack-5.6.0-java/modules/arcsight/configuration"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,042][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://172.19.238.10:9200/]}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,042][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://172.19.238.10:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,089][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://172.19.238.10:9200/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,089][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,113][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,116][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://172.19.238.10:9200"]}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,121][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://172.19.238.10:9200/]}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,121][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://172.19.238.10:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,124][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://172.19.238.10:9200/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,127][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,130][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,133][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://172.19.238.10:9200"]}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,138][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://172.19.238.10:9200/]}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,139][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://172.19.238.10:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,145][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://172.19.238.10:9200/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,146][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,149][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,152][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://172.19.238.10:9200"]}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,155][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://172.19.238.10:9200/]}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,156][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://172.19.238.10:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,158][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://172.19.238.10:9200/"}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,159][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,165][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,170][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://172.19.238.10:9200"]}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,173][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,306][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-11-01T10:12:47,349][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

The proba.json's content is the following:

```
{"name": "nobody","age": "1000"}
```

Version 5.6.0 is used both from elasticsearch and logstash.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In your `file` input, you need to add `codec => json` as well.

Comment: Tried, but did not help. No additional entries in the logs.

Comment: You need to start over from the beginning of your file, i.e. add `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`

Comment: Still nothing. :(